# What can go wrong with ssh port-forwarding HTTP/HTTPS sites?

Tags: ssh

I am trying to figure out how `ssh` port forwarding works. I'm very puzzled as to the different problems I am seeing.

First, a basic example: `ssh -L 8080:www.ubuntuforums.org:80 localhost`. After logging into my local machine, navigating to `localhost:8080` in Chrome gets me to `http://www.canonical.com/`. If I navigate directly to `http://www.ubuntuforums.org/` in my Chrome, I instead end up at `http://ubuntuforums.org/`. What is going on here? Why do I not end up at `ubuntuforums.org` but instead `www.canonical.com`?

Second, changing the website and port: `ssh -L 8888:learnlayout.com:80 localhost`. Navigating to `http://localhost:8888` in Chrome I just hang forever. `wget http://localhost:8888` gives me the following `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<title>Transmission Forward</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.location = "http://24.218.24.189:8080/"
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Stand By...</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Is `ssh` not handling redirects correctly or something when I point to it in my browser?

Third, `ssh -L 8888:imgur.com:80 localhost`. In my browser I get the following error: `Fastly error: unknown domain: localhost. Please check that this domain has been added to a service.`. `wget localhost:8888` gives me:

```
--2016-05-07 16:36:47--  http://localhost:8887/
Resolving localhost... ::1, 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost|::1|:8888... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 500 Domain Not Found
2016-05-07 16:36:47 ERROR 500: Domain Not Found.
```

This diversity of errors is really befuddling me. Is there anything obvious about `ssh` tunneling I am missing? Should these be working and maybe my network or router is up to something?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do local port fowarding using localhost as the ssh target machine... are you sure that you can do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Background

### SSH

You are using SSH to establish a secure connection between two systems, authenticating the user to the remote endpoint and then setting up a tunnel inside that connection so that all connections to a specific port on your local machine are sent - through the tunnel - to a different host and port

### HTTP

Using a browser or tool like `wget` you are making HTTP request to your local machine and port. Whatever response you get from that endpoint is interpreted by the originating tool according to the HTTP specification.

## Your issue

When you make HTTP requests the **responses you get are not what you expect**. If you try to access `example.org` on your local machine as `localhost:8888` thanks to an SSH tunnel, you are not getting the actual page as if you were browsing `example.org` directly.

### Explanation

Most pages/sites are domain-aware. That means that its **functionality is tightly tied to the domain on which they are configured to serve**.

In your examples there are an assortment of scenarios. Websites forcing a particular URL to access them, a website redirection using javascript and even a webserver that does not know what site to serve based off that URL. The explanation is the same for all of them: they are not prepared to be accessed with an URL different than what they consider the standard URL.

In my experience, the domain with which a site will be accessed is something one can assume. Some configurations can be made to enforce a particular version of that domain (like adding or removing `www`), but hardly anything else. Such configuration can be made in the webserver - or caching layer in front of it - or the application itself (WordPress has a setting for its domain that it will enforce on its own). The exception are applications that can be accessed with multiple DNSs and most web frameworks have a way to support that scenario, but they mostly need a backend configuration to determine the list of domains they will serve.

## Solution

For browsing the web from a different connection or using a tunnel: **use an HTTP proxy**. In particular, SSH's option `-d PORT` will create a SOCKS proxy that you can configure in most HTTP tools to tunnel connections.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thank you. Does that mean that many of [the examples here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/PortForwarding) are incorrect? There are loads of similar examples out there implying `-L` can be used for HTTP. What kind of information/sessions can be sent via `-L` forwarding? Just `ssh` sessions? Basic TCP/UDP packets? Many examples seem to be incomplete.

Comment: Ah, I just created an example that seems to work. `ssh -L 8888:localhost:8889 localhost`. Then listen with `nc -l 8889`. In the `ssh` session, `echo "hello" | nc localhost 8888`. Netcat listening on 8889 will output `hello`.

Comment: Whatever you send through the tunnel will get to the other side of the connection. As you experienced, it is protocol-agnostic

Comment: This answer saves my life!

Comment: i wrote this to make sure the tunnel is open properly :
nc -z localhost 3211 || echo 'no tunnel open'; exit